# Exception "Unable to resolve ObjectType 'getAmount' "

Tags: drools

In Drools, I created a drl file with the following content:

```
import com.myorg.model.UserAccount;
import function com.myorg.utils.UserAccountHelper.getAmount;

rule "Classification userC"
when
    $user : UserAccount(_age < 50);
    $amount: getAmount($user, "single");
then
    $user.set_userClassification("userC");    
end
```

in Java I have a static method UserAccountHelper.getAmount

```
public static double getAmount(UserAccount account, String status)
{
   double amount = 0d;
   switch(status)
   {
      case "single":
         if (account.canBeFullyRefunded)
            amount = 1000;
         else
            amount = 100;
      default:
         amount = 0d;
   }
   return amount;
}
```

I am getting an Exception "Unable to resolve ObjectType 'getAmount'" when validating the drl file.Someone can help?
I am using Drools 7.37.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not the way you invoke static methods of a class in DRL. I would recommend you to take a look at the documentation to understand the syntax better.

If you want to invoke a static (or instance) method in a Pattern, you can do it like this:

```
rule "Classification userC"
when
    $user : UserAccount(
        _age < 50, 
        $amount: getAmount(this, "single")
    )
then
    $user.set_userClassification("userC");    
end
```